# Visual studio 2015 - node.js, express 4 using typescript project does not compile

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015, express-4

There does not exist a project template that uses Typescript with Express4, there does however exist typescript template using express3. Is it that TS is incompatible with Express4.

I tried by creating regular TS with Express3 template, uninstalled Express3 npm package and added Express4 package. It did not compile.
I also added TDS as explained in https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs and it gave more errors like cannot find property express.favicon().

Comment: Are you using version 4 [express.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts)? `express.favicon` is in version 3. Express 4 uses [serve-favicon](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html). You will need to have `d.ts` files for middlewares that are not built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create "Basic Node.js Express 4 Application" JavaScipt type application and after remove **app.js** and add **app.ts**. After it restart VS and now you should see **TS** as project icon.

Also run this in package manager console

```
npm install tsd -g
tsd install express --save
```

and add this line in the top of **app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="path to your tsd.d.ts" />
```

usually tsd.d.ts will be placed in the root of your solution folder in **typings** folder